# How do I find a file in a list of directories set in an environment variable?

Tags: bash, find

I am trying to find a file that might be located in one of the folders in the `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Basically I am trying to:

```
 find $LD_LIBRARY_PATH -name "*libdl*"
```

However the above command fails because of multiple entries in the variable and separated my a `:`. I get the error:

```
    No such file or directory
```

How to accomplish this?

Comment: it doesn't work?  What does LD_LIBRARY_PATH expand to?

Comment: It doesn't work because of the column separator in the environment variable

Comment: @jesse_b Presumably it expands to something like `/some/dir:/some/other/dir`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use word-splitting with a colon, since *PATH variables are colon-separated lists of directories.

Uncomment the lines below to save and restore the old IFS (recommended):

```
#oldIFS="$IFS"
IFS=:
set -o noglob # disable the glob part of the split+glob operator
              # unlikely to be needed as library directories
              # are unlikely to have wildcard characters in their
              # name.
find -H $LD_LIBRARY_PATH -mindpeth 1 -maxdepth 1 -name "*libdl*"
#IFS="$oldIFS"
#set +o noglob
```

`-H` is needed in case any of those `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` components are symlinks. `-mindepth 1` (a GNU extension, though found in many other implementations these days) to avoid matching on those components themselves, `-maxdepth` to skip searching in sub-directories (which are not meant to be searched by the dynamic linker).

Bash shorthand assuming the default value of `$IFS` and if the directories are known not to contain any of the characters of that default value of `$IFS` (space, tab and newline) nor wildcard characters, and none of those directories are symlinks nor have subdirectories, and the names of those directories themselves won't match the pattern:

```
find -H ${LD_LIBRARY_PATH//:/ } -name "*libdl*"
```

That uses a [substitution command](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) that transforms every colon into a space (a feature copied from ksh93).

With `zsh`, without having to make any of those assumptions:

```
print -rC1 - ${(s[:])^LD_LIBRARY_PATH}/*libdl*(ND)
```

Comment: Regarding restoring `IFS`, one may also use a subshell for that: `(IFS=:; find $LD_LIBRARY_PATH -name "*libdl*")`